# HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\open\command but per user

Tags: windows, shell, windows-registry

I use a third party file manager instead of Windows explorer and set it by adding the key `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\open\command]` to the registry and it works like a charm.
But now I need to have another user on my Windows 10, and for this user I want to keep Windows explorer as a default file manager.

**The question**: is it possible to set `...Directory\shell\open\command` per user to keep each user with their settings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `HKCR` is not saved to a file like `HKCU` or `HKLM`. It is in fact created in memory by combining entries found under `HKCU\Software\Classes` and `HKLM\Software\Classses`.

You'll find your edited entry under:

- `HKLM\Software\Classses\Directory\Shell\Open\Command`

You'll want to create per-user entries under:

- `HKCU\Software\Classses\Directory\Shell\Open\Command`

The per-user entries will override the `HKLM` entries, so it will still be there for new users.

Note that you can only create an `HKCU` (HK Current User) entry for the currently logged on user unless you use `Load Hive...` to access a different user's `ntuser.dat` file.

But since you only want behavior for your login modified, you want to:

1. Edit the `HKLM` entry back to default behavior.
2. Create your `HKCU` entry to modify behavior under your profile

Comment: Yep. I was in a hurry and mistyped. Edited now .